# How can I add an exception handler to the SERVER side of GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, exception

I want to wrap all outgoing exceptions from the GWT Server (only the server, nothing on the client):

```
public class AuthServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements AuthService {
    public String loginAttemt(String username, String password) {
        AwesomeUser user = AwesomeUserDao.forUsername(username);
        if(BCrpyt.checkpw(user.getPasshash(), password)) {
            String code = magicallyGenerateErrorCode();
            logger.error("Invalid login attempt - error code"  + code);
            throw new AwesomeException("password", "Invalid username or password", code);
        }
    }
}

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("auth")
public interface AuthService extends RemoteService {
    String loginAttempt(String username, String password) throws AwesomeException;
}

public interface AuthServiceAsync {
    void loginAttempt(String username, String password, AsyncCallback<String> callback) throws AwesomeException;
}
```

Now right now, this works. On my client side, I simply do something like this (`getField(String)` is a little customization I made for unrelated reasons but it gets the point across)

```
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    if(caught instanceof AwesomeException) {
        AwesomeException a = (AwesomeException)caught;
        getField(a.getfield()).setErrorText(a.getText());
        getField("error-code").setText(a.getCode());
    }
}
```

And yes, this works as expected. But imagine for a moment that `user` was `null` - some of you may have read that going "Oh man, he might have a NPE there if the username doesn't exist" and you're absolutely right. And for sure, I do defensively code such things. However, I will not catch all those circumstances. I would like to add, somewhere, an exception handler that catches all those exceptions and wraps them in `AwesomeException` - particularly so I can pass the relevant error code to the user so they can contact support with what went wrong. I don't want to rely on the programmer always remembering every single possible null and illegal argument and all the other runtime exceptions. I don't want them complacent of course, but I do want to make sure that a user ALWAYS has an error code to contact support with.

(The error code is actually a request ID - every request has an ID and all log messages use that ID when they print - so if they report the error code, we can very easily see all the log messages with that request and troubleshoot the error.)

I tried tracing the call back but it ends up getting lost in the RPC class. But surely I'm not the first person to try to intercept GWT exceptions being emitted by the server, right?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by extending the `RemoteServiceServlet` and do the exception handling for example in `processCall(RPCRequest rpcRequest)` or `doUnexpectedFailure(Throwable e)`.

E.g.:

> This method is called only for exceptions or errors that are not part
>   of the service method's signature, or that result from
>   SecurityExceptions, SerializationExceptions, or other failures within
>   the RPC framework.

Meaning any NPE etc. can be mapped to custom exception here.

```
  protected void doUnexpectedFailure(Throwable e) {
    try {
      getThreadLocalResponse().reset();
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
      /*
       * If we can't reset the request, the only way to signal that something
       * has gone wrong is to throw an exception from here. It should be the
       * case that we call the user's implementation code before emitting data
       * into the response, so the only time that gets tripped is if the object
       * serialization code blows up.
       */
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to report failure", e);
    }
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();

    String code = magicallyGenerateErrorCode();
    AwesomeException awesomeException = new AwesomeException("error", "Unexpected Error. Pls contact support", code);

    RPCServletUtils.writeResponseForUnexpectedFailure(servletContext,
        getThreadLocalResponse(), awesomeException);
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mention in the post, processCall just delegates to `RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse` which I don't have control over.

Comment: You also checked if `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doUnexpectedFailure` works for you? If not I still have an working example that I will look up for you then...

Comment: If I did the `doUnexpectedFailure` then I might as well just wrap every one of my servlet methods in try-catch methods.

Comment: From my understanding you want to wrap all unchecked exceptions. This wrapping has to be done somewhere and having one class, that does this, is still much better than adding a try-catch block to all your servlet methods. But it seems like I am getting something wrong?!

Comment: My current strategy (not complete yet, been busy today) is to modify the gwt source of `RPC.encodeResponseForFailedRequest` to add `if(RPC.exceptionIntercepter != null) cause = exceptionInterceptor.intercept(cause);` - it compiles and should work I just haven't had a chance to test it yet. In my web listener, i have `RPC.setExceptionInterceptr((c) -> { log(c); if(c instanceof AwesomeException) return c; return new AwesomeException(c);});` (Not exactly the same, but this comment is only so big.

Comment: IMHO changing the GWT source code is more risky and requires much more effort than just using the `doUnexpectedFailure` in the `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet` which designed to do exactly what you want: wrapping whatever uncaught exception in your custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the service extending `RemoteServiceServlet`, you can create your own servlet and delegate to the `RemoteServiceServlet` like:

```
public class GwtServiceServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        Object delegate = ...;

        RemoteServiceServlet remoteServiceServlet = new RemoteServiceServlet(delegate);
        remoteServiceServlet.init(getServletConfig());
        remoteServiceServlet.doPost(request, response);
    }
}
```

Where `delegate` is an implementation of the service interface. Because you're controlling the creation of the service implementation, then you can now wrap it in a proxy to convert exceptions or do logging.

Comment: As I mentioned on Tobika's answer, I'm not seeing a route that allows me to wrap the Exception that would be thrown.